# Extensible OCR engine for .Net

Tags: .net, ocr, extensible

I'm looking for free (or free to try) OCR engine for .net which is extensible (I want to add not supported language(s)). 
I know some OCR engines, but I need a suggestion. Which is better and extensible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What languages do you want to add? ABBYY OCR engine supports [198 languages for OCR and 113 for ICR](http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk_windows/technical_specifications/ocr_languages/) and it's way much better that its competitors. It's free to try, trial version can be requested [here](http://www.abbyy.com/sdk/fre/request?purpose=trial). I work @ ABBYY and can provide you some more details on our engines if necessary.

Comment: Just curious. It supports Abkhaz language and not Georgian http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_alphabet.

Comment: Abkhaz language uses Cyrillic alphabet, which was already supported by OCR engine, so implementing Georgian language recognition is much more complecated.